# How to change the CSS property (border color) of input tag of form on button click and also submit data?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have test2.php file which has html form inside php tags in echo ""; like this, I also had submit button inside form, my problem is that on submit click the form data is sent to reciever page via form method post, but also change the css property of input type such that it is confirmed that particular form input is submitted.

content of test2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .form-filled{
            border: 1px solid #ffff00;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id='form1' action='test2.php' method='post'>
        <label></label> 

            <input type='text' name='fname' value='Rinku' >
            <input type='text' name='lname' value='yadav' >
            <input type='text' name='deg' value='BE' >
            <input type='text' name='course' value='CSE' >

        <label>checkbox: </label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check' onchange='checkfunction()'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit1' onclick="alert('submit 1 button pressed');">
        <input type=submit name='submit2' value='Submit2' onclick='myfunction()'>
    </form>


<?php

    echo "<form id='form2' action='test2.php' method='post'>";

        echo "<label></label>";

        echo "<input type='text' name='fname' value='Rinku' >";
        echo "<input type='text' name='lname' value='yadav' >";
        echo "<input type='text' name='deg' value='BE' >";
        echo "<input type='text' name='course' value='CSE' >";
        echo "<label>checkbox: </label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' onchange='checkfunction()'>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit1' onclick="."alert('submit 1 button pressed');".">";
        echo "<input type=submit name='submit2' value='Submit2' onclick='myfunction()'>";

    echo "</form>";

?>


    <script type='text/javascript'>


        function myfunction(){
            alert('Submit 2 is clicked!');

            $('input').addClass("form-filled");

        }

        function checkfunction(){
            alert('checkbox is check/unchecked');

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly applying the CSS from jQuery. It is better to add class on the input elements and apply CSS on that class.

Change this line:

```
$('input').css({'border: 1px solid #ffff00;'});
```

with this line:

```
$('input').addClass("form-filled");
```

By the way what is `elm` in this line:

```
document.elm.style.border = "3px solid #FF0000";
```

It is also throwing an error as `elm` not defined.

Here is the demo in which I have just changed the border on class.

```js
function myfunction(){
    alert('Submit 2 is clicked!');
    $('input[type=text]').addClass("form-filled");
}

function checkfunction(){
    alert('checkbox is check/unchecked');
}

$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.form-filled{
    border: 1px solid #ffff00;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id='form1' action='test2.php' method='post'>
        <label></label> 

            <input type='text' name='fname' value='Rinku' >
            <input type='text' name='lname' value='yadav' >
            <input type='text' name='deg' value='BE' >
            <input type='text' name='course' value='CSE' >

        <label>checkbox: </label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check' onchange='checkfunction()'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit1' onclick="alert('submit 1 button pressed');">
        <input type=submit name='submit2' value='Submit2' onclick='myfunction()'>
    </form>
    
    <hr>

    <form id='form2' action='' method='post'>
        <label></label>
        <input type='text' name='fname' value='Rinku' >
        <input type='text' name='lname' value='yadav' >
        <input type='text' name='deg' value='BE' >
        <input type='text' name='course' value='CSE' >
        <label>checkbox: </label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check' onchange='checkfunction()'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit1' onclick="."alert('submit 1 button pressed');".">
        <input type=submit name='submit2' value='Submit2' onclick='myfunction()'>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Example with highlighting only the clicked form fields:**

```js
$("form .submit2").click(function() {
    alert('Submit 2 is clicked!');
    var formId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    $('#' + formId + ' input[type=text]').addClass("form-filled");
});

function checkfunction(){
    alert('checkbox is check/unchecked');
}

$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.form-filled{
    border: 1px solid #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id='form1' action='test2.php' method='post'>
        <label></label> 

            <input type='text' name='fname' value='Rinku' >
            <input type='text' name='lname' value='yadav' >
            <input type='text' name='deg' value='BE' >
            <input type='text' name='course' value='CSE' >

        <label>checkbox: </label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check' onchange='checkfunction()'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit1' onclick="alert('submit 1 button pressed');">
        <input type=submit name='submit2' value='Submit2' class="submit2">
    </form>
    
    <hr>

    <form id='form2' action='' method='post'>
        <label></label>
        <input type='text' name='fname' value='Rinku' >
        <input type='text' name='lname' value='yadav' >
        <input type='text' name='deg' value='BE' >
        <input type='text' name='course' value='CSE' >
        <label>checkbox: </label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check' onchange='checkfunction()'>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit1' onclick="alert('submit 1 button pressed');">
        <input type=submit name='submit2' value='Submit2' class="submit2">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but still the border color of input tag is not changed when submit 2 is clicked

Comment: it need to change from red color to #ffff00

Comment: @Rink16 Add class from jQuery and apply the css on that class which is the better option for input fields.

Comment: @Rink16 I have added the solution by which class are added on all the input fields. You just need to move style on that class only.

Comment: I updated the php code above in question which i am trying but still the border color is not changed on submit 2 click

Comment: @Rink16 I have added your code in demo. Your PHP gets removed from. In the demo, you can see that when you on submit2 color gets changed.

Comment: Thanks for your help but if i pass form id with click of submit2 because both the input border color are changed while only submit 2 of form 1 was clicked. why?

Comment: Where you have passed the form id?

Comment: I am thinking to do but not able to figure it out so that i can distinguish between the submit2 of different forms

Comment: Now it is happening like if i click on submit2 both the input border color get change while i click on submit2 of first form.

Comment: I am thinking to pass the form id somewhere, $('input[type=text]').addClass("form-filled");, is it right?

Comment: @Rink16 It will be better if just add the class on submit button and change the event to call the function. If you like so I can provide you the example.

Comment: it means upon adding class to submit only button color will change

Comment: @Rink16 Check the second example I have added in the answer.

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed, Thanks a lot

Comment: what about the post data if i need to submit that also after change of color

Comment: also how to retain the changed color after i refresh the page

Comment: can we retain the changed css property by using some local storage, so that we get the changed css of page on refresh